# How to partition hard disk to save data during Ubuntu reinstallation

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

How to partition 160GB hard disk such as whenever I reinstall or upgrade my data on it should be safe such as it shouldn't get deleted?

For example in Windows XP, I have four partitions like c,d,e,f. Whenever I  install new Window XP or anything in `c:`, my data in `d:`, `e:` and `f:` are safe. But this doesn't happen in Linux my all data were wiped out when I changed Ubuntu from 10.10 to 12.04.

Comment: You simply make more partitions using the livecd and gparted. And keep your files in your /home folder and not in a single Ubuntu partition.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu (like all UNIX-like systems) organizes files in a hierarchical tree. At the top of this tree is **`/`** (the **root** directory) where *everything* else resides including the **`/home`** directory.

The **`/home`** directory is where all users' personal files, folders and settings resides such as music, photos, videos, etc. - everything you see in the Home folder in Nautilus.

Thus, creating a separate partition for **`/home`** will allow you to **reinstall** Ubuntu and still **keep** all your personal files and settings safe.

**Option A**

Create a separate `/home` partition using Live CD:

1. Boot from a LiveCD and select "**Try Ubuntu**".
2. Launch **GParted** from Dash.

   - In the GParted window, select which partition you want to resize to create space for `/home`.
   - Select the unallocated space gained from the above step and click on **Partition → New** from the menu.
   - Select the filesystem you want, ext3 or ext4.
   - Click **Apply**, **Close** then **Quit**.
3. Now, you need to tell Ubuntu to use the new partition as `/home`.

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   this will open the `fstab` file in gedit, now add the following line:

   ```
   /dev/sdxy /home ext4 defaults 0 0
   ```

   where 'sdxy' is the partition you just created, i.e. /dev/sda2
4. **Save** and **close** the file.
5. **Reboot**.

**Option B**

Create a separate `/home` partition **during installation**:

1. Boot from a LiveCD and select "**Install Ubuntu**".
2. In the next window click on **Continue**.
3. In the "**Installation Type**" window, select "**Something Else**" then "**Continue**.
4. In the next window, select a free (unallocated) space and click on "**Add**".

   You have to create at least 2 partitions: `/` and `/home`

   In the Create partition window:

   - Set the size for the partition
   - Select the filesystem (ext3 or ext4)
   - Select the mount point, use:

     - `/` for root
     - `/home` for home
5. Once you're done creating partitions, you should have one ext3/ext4 partition with a mount point of `/` and one ext3/ext4 partition with a mount point of `/home`. Depending on your situation, you may also have a swap partition.
6. If you're satisfied with your partition scheme, click **Forward** to continue with the installation.

Comment: You don't need a separate /home partition for this, simply use manual partitioning when you reinstall and do *not* check the format tick box.